# customizing UIActivityViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to attach a screenshot to my mail in my `UIActivityViewController` without the screenshot being saved to my library. Here's my code so far:

```
-(IBAction)ActivityController:(id)sender {{



    NSString *shareString = @"";
    UIImage *shareImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];


    NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:shareString,shareImage, shareUrl, nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *exportData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image ,1.0);
    [mailController addAttachmentData:exportData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Screenshot.jpeg"];
```

There is no screenshot attached to the email.

And how do I create an action when I press the cancel button in `UIActivityViewcontroller`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIActivityViewController help you easy to share data from iOS6.
Just call it, input data and click which one you want to share.
Don't init MFMailComposeViewController.

This is sample common code working in iPad and iPhone

```
-(IBAction)actionButton:(id)sender {
  //Popover for iPad
    //if (self.popover) {
    //    if ([self.popover isPopoverVisible]) {
      //      return;
      //  } else {
       //     [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
      //      self.popover = nil;
      //  }
   // }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSString *shareText = @"Share Text";
    NSURL *shareURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shareURL.com"];

    /* iOS 6 sharing, */
    UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];

    NSArray *activityItems = @[image, shareText, shareURL];
    NSArray *applicationActivities = @[activity];
    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[];

    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
    activityController.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    // switch for iPhone and iPad.
   // if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
     //   self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityController];
      //  self.popover.delegate = self;
       // [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
   // } else {
        [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{
            NSLog(@"Activity complete");
        }];
   // }


}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to know when Cancel button click, you need to modify a little in presentViewController

```
    [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
     {
         if (!act) {
             NSLog(@"Cancel");
         } 
     }];
```

Comment: I'm receiving the eroror "property popover not found

Comment: This code use for Universal App, delete Popover code for iPad

Comment: I only need to create for Iphone

Comment: Great it worked! but I want to create an action when the cancel button is pressed. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm checking doc. Don't find any delegate or method to catch cancel pressed.

Comment: The app crashes and it displays: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I run OK, don't know why you get these errors! UIActivityController only work on iOS6, maybe you test on iOS5